# Plotly dash population bar chart not working properly

Tags: python, charts, plotly, plotly-dash

I wanted to do a simple population bar chart, but I can't understand it.
My dataset is:

```
Age,Women,Men
"18-24",1.8%,2%
"25-34",20.9%,13.7%
"35-44",19.3%,14.6%
"45-54",9.3%,8%
"55-64",3.6%,2.9%
"65+",2.3%,1.6%
```

And the code is:

```
example_graph11  =  px.bar(facebook2, x='Age', y=['Men', 'Women'], barmode='stack',

          title = 'Percentage of Facebook fans by age and gender')
```

But the result is weird, and I don't understand what input data should I put. I tried with a pyramid chart as well and it didn't work.

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLWP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly is ether normalizing (dividing the value over itself) all your entries, because you only have 1 point per interval everything's turning to 1. Or thinking the data is a string because of the %, so its counting and plotting the individual values.

You can try something like this, removing the % and then plotting:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
interval=["18-24", "25-34", "35-44","45-54", "55-64","65+"]
Men = [2,13.7,14.6,8,2.9,1.6]
Women = [1.8, 20.9, 19.3, 9.3,3.6,2.3]

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Women', x=interval, y=Women),
    go.Bar(name='Men', x=interval, y=Men)
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'age': ['18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+'],
    'women': [1.8, 20.9, 19.3, 9.3, 3.6, 2.3],
    'men': [2, 13.7, 14.6, 8, 2.9, 1.6]
}

x = data['age']
y_women = data['women']
y_men = data['men']

plt.bar(x, y_women, color='purple', label='Women')
plt.bar(x, y_men, color='green', label='Men')

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Population %')
plt.title('Population by age and gender')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but it's for a dashboard so I need plotly!